# How do i deterministically generate n unique numbers within a range from a GUID?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

A concrete example.

If i have a range of 1-300, how can a generate 5 unique numbers within that range using GUID `"EDAAE218-FBF0-4B66-AEAF-FB036FBF69F4"`.  Applying the same algorithm to the GUID should result in the same 5 numbers being chosen every time.

The input doesn't have to be a GUID, it's just acting as some sort of key.

Some context for the problem i am trying to solve. I have a hard coded List of values that contains roughly 300 or so elements. I am trying to find a way to select 20 elements from this list that always produces the same elements.

My idea was to generate a GUID which could be handed out to multiple users. When those users input the GUID into the app, the same 20 elements would be returned for everyone.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, when you put deterministic and random in the same sentence.

Comment: How is it random if it's the same output always?

Comment: Just use any hashing algorithm where you require a salt key. The GUID would serve as the salt. One in specific is to use bcrypt hash

Comment: Sorry, my description was quite messy. I have updated the question and provided some context for the problem.

Comment: A GUID would not be my first choice - they are meant to be unique not random.  You might be looking for a Mersenne Twister

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this question - it seems completely reasonable.

Comment: You can use the GUID's hash code (or the hash code of any string) as a seed to a random number generator, then use that to select the items. For a given GUID and set of items, this should consistently produce the same values. I would add this as an answer, but the question is currently on hold: `var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 300);

        var g = new Guid("EDAAE218-FBF0-4B66-AEAF-FB036FBF69F4");

        var r = new Random(g.GetHashCode());

        var selected = items.OrderBy(_ => r.Next()).Take(5).ToList();`

Comment: @AdamBrown It wasn't reasonable in its original formulation, but it is now. I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: @syco_link The answer you have accepted does not work for your requirement because it can quite easily select non-unique values. Have you tried the approach I suggested here in the comments?

Comment: @syco_link Adam has now fixed the issue in his answer with it producing duplicates. I still think you should try my approach :) but if not, at least update your code to use his new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guid is effectively a 128-bit number. So you can easily do this provided that the number of bits required to represent your numbers are fewer than the number of bits in the guid (128). You don't need to hash the guid or anything like that.

EDIT:

Now that I know what you need (i.e. a unique seed to be derived from a guid, you could do it this way) - but you could equally hand out a 32-bit number and avoid the guid-to-int conversion.

EDIT2: Using GetHashCode as per suggestion from comments above.

EDIT 3: Producing unique numbers.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var guid = new Guid("bdc39e63-5947-4704-9e12-ec66c8773742");
     Console.WriteLine(guid);
     var numbers = FindNumbersFromGuid(guid, 16, 8);

     Console.WriteLine("Numbers: ");
     foreach (var elem in numbers)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(elem);
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
 }

 private static int[] FindNumbersFromGuid(Guid input,
     int maxNumber, int numberCount)
 {
     if (numberCount > maxNumber / 2) throw new ArgumentException("Choosing too many numbers.");
     var seed = input.GetHashCode();
     var random = new Random(seed);
     var chosenSoFar = new HashSet<int>();
     return Enumerable.Range(0, numberCount)
         .Select(e =>
         {
             var ret = random.Next(0, maxNumber);
             while (chosenSoFar.Contains(ret))
             {
                 ret = random.Next(0, maxNumber);
             }
             chosenSoFar.Add(ret);
             return ret;
         }).ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: `return Enumerable.Range(0, numberCount)
        .Select(e => random.Next(0, maxNumber)).ToArray();` could easily produce duplicate values.

Comment: Also, your algorithm only utilizes the first 4 bytes of the GUID and throws away the other 12.

Comment: Changed to use GetHashCode, which will hash all 16 bytes. Another option might be to initialise 4 instances of Random, and then hash the values together, thereby using all 16 bytes of the GUID. From what the OP was asking, this is sufficient, though.

Comment: Ok, but that was the lesser of the two problems I pointed out, the greater being that _it can quite frequently produce non-unique values_ (the title of this question specifically states that OP wants unique values). For example, running your code with the GUID `721550ec-b930-4099-a399-34432f102eb8` produces the values **148**, **148**, 141, 132, and 22.

Comment: Fixed. Now produces unique numbers.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks. :)